# Why do I need those tags?

Tags: html, css, tags

Why do I need those tags ? :
**Footer

Main

Article

Section

Form**

Even if I don’t use those tags, I can get the same result, so what's the point of using these tags at all?

Comment: @j08691 The OP's point is to understand why they're useful - those tags don't appear to change how the page looks, so they're wondering why they'd want to use them at all.

Comment: @j08691 I don't agree that it's off-topic. I assume that they found them in some documentation and tried them out and noticed that the page looked the same. I actually think it's a reasonable question if you're new to HTML.

Comment: Thank you all for your support , appreciated .. ! 

I’ve check it out , and I’ve decided to *use* those tags for better “organization”

Comment: @ItayK  Hey, hopping in real quick to check whether I solved your issue or do I need to ameliorate my skills?

Answer (score 2):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML_sections_and_outlines):

> The HTML5 specification introduced several semantic sectioning elements to help organize the structure of documents. Semantic sectioning elements are specifically designed to communicate structural meaning to browsers and other technologies interpreting the document on behalf of users, such as screen readers and voice assistants.

> Semantic sectioning elements clarify the larger-scale structures within a document. They are intended to enhance the limited semantics of earlier versions of HTML, which included only the  tag as a generic mechanism for grouping related content

To mention also:

> **Important**: There are no implementations of the proposed outline algorithm in web browsers nor assistive technology; it was never part of a final W3C specification. Therefore the outline algorithm should not be used to convey document structure to users. Authors are advised to use heading rank (h1-h6) to convey document structure.

and this is why you can't find any resources, because it is not standardized, and so it hasn't a common significance

Answer (score 0):

Originally, HTML was all about formatting. That's why you have tags like `b` and `i`. Those tags tell you how the page is supposed to look, but they tell you nothing about what the data actually *means*. Over time, there's been a movement towards separating meaning and the appearance (especially with the advent of HTML5). That's why those tags exist.

With regards to your list, note that the `form` tag is different than the other ones you list - that particular one means that all of the input tags inside the form are intended to be sent to a server.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can definitely do all such things without all these tags but it helps the browser to understand your code better and it will help you when you make big/complex website to understand edit your code easily.